# PODIO - Items: Calculate - JSON POST format for date filtering

Tags: json, podio

https://developers.podio.com/doc/items/calculate-67633

I'm struggling with the key & value formatting for filtering on a calculate request in an app with 13000+ items over 3 years. I can filter on normal fields fine using the request shown below but when it comes to filtering by date, let's say all of 2016, I can't get a successful response. I've tried variations of start/end, to/from and joining the two dates with a hyphen and nothing makes for a successful response. I guess the first question here is, is it actually possible to use a date filter within a calculate request and if yes then how do you correctly format it?

Successful request with filter on category field -

```
{ "limit": 100, "aggregation": "sum", 
"formula": [ { "type": "field", "value": xxxxxxxxx } ],
"groupings": [ { "type": "field", "value": zzzzzzzzz, "sub_value": "month" } ],
"filters": [ { "key": yyyyyyyy, "values": 1 } ] }
```

Unsuccessful date filter formats -

```
"filters": [ { "key": 80595722, "values": "2017-01-01-2017-06-30" } ] 

"filters": [ "key": 80595722, "values": [{"from": "2016-01-01", "to" : "2016-12-31"}] ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample request:

```
'{"aggregation":"sum",
  "formula":[{"type":"field","value":130553805}],
  "grouping":{},
  "sorting":null,
  "filters":{"134188255":{"from":"2017-08-01","to":"2017-10-12"}}}'
```